# KubernetesPodOperator not recognizing the service_account_name

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I created a `serviceAccount` resource named `my-app-cluster-access`. Then supply that resource name in the `service_account_name` argument in the `KubernetesPodOperator`. But I keep getting the error

```
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:my-release-name:default\" cannot create resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}
```

The message seem to indicate that the supplied value of the `service_account_name` is not being applied since the message still has the `default` text. I check the `KubernetesPodOperator` source code and look likes the mapping is there.

Before I created `ServiceAccount` resource, I also got that same error message. Do I need to create a `ServiceAccount` resource to use that operator? I need to be able to use `KubernetesPodOperator` and so far is not working after adding the `ServiceAccount`. I already set the `in_cluster` arg to `True`.

Answer (score 3):

By default every namespace has a service account `default` The `default` service account does not have permission to create pods.

In your case a `default` service account from namespace `my-release-name` is trying to create a pod in `default` namespace.

You can check if a service account named `default` from namespace `my-release-name` has permission to create pods in `default` namespace.

```
kubectl auth can-i create pods -n default--as=system:serviceaccount:my-release-name:default
```

This will return no.

So you can create a role like below

```
kubectl create clusterrole pod-creator --verb=create,get,list,watch --resource=pods
```

and a clusterrolebinding

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding pod-creator-clusterrolebinding --clusterrole=pod-creator --serviceaccount=my-release-name:default
```

Above should work without a need to create a new service account.